# How to use variables to create dynamic events

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have some dynamically created controls and panels.  One control is a combobox that displays color.  When the user selects a color I display the word in the combo and the color in a picture box.  This works fine on the static portion.  But I cant figure out how to display the color since the dynamic controls are data driven and I never know how many there are, so I cant hard code it.

I need this event:

```
Private Sub cboSRDColor_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboSRDColor_1.SelectedIndexChanged

    picSRDColor_1.BackColor = Color.FromName([Enum].Parse(GetType(KnownColor), cboSRDColor_1.Text).ToString)

End Sub
```

To be dynamically created.  The problem is the control name is created with a variable and this does not work the way I've tried it.

Creating the controls:

```
InitializeControlComboboxColor(eColumn.Second, cboColor)
With cboColor
    .Name = "cboDetailColor_" & Suffix
    .Top = 131
End With
Parent.Controls.Add(cboColor)

InitializeControlPicturebox(eColumn.Second, pic)
With pic
    .Name = "picDetailColor_" & Suffix
    .Top = 131
End With
Parent.Controls.Add(pic)
AddHandler cboColor.DrawItem, AddressOf cboColorPicker_DrawItem
AddHandler cboColor.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf MarkTableDetailsDirty
```

How can I add the picturebox in the event handler if I don't know the name until run time?

```
AddHandler cboColor.SelectedIndexChanged, Sub(sender2, eventargs2)
                                              ***picDetailColor_ & Suffix*** .BackColor = Color.FromName([Enum].Parse(GetType(KnownColor), cboSRDColor.Text).ToString)
                                          End Sub
```

The issue is marked with asterisk.  There will be another issue near the end of the line.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are the comboboxes and pictureboxes always added as a pair? If so, you could make a simple class or structure with each of those as a member, then you don't have to worry about the name properties at all since they have variable references to each other

Comment: If your interrelated controls are close to one another, you could try to make a new control which includes both. This way the event would be owned by the new class, which means that inside the new class you would know the sub-control's names even though the new control has been created dynamically inside your current form.

Comment: I would probably assign the related `PictureBox` to the `Tag` property of the `ComboBox`. In the event handler, cast the `sender` as type `ComboBox` and then get the `PictureBox` from its `Tag`. I think the best alternative is to use a `Dictionary(Of ComboBox, PictureBox)` to create the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then first thought is do something like this:

```
Private Sub AddColor(Top As Integer)
    InitializeControlComboboxColor(eColumn.Second, cboColor)
    With cboColor
        .Top = Top
    End With
    Parent.Controls.Add(cboColor)

    InitializeControlPicturebox(eColumn.Second, pic)
    With pic
        .Top = Top
    End With
    Parent.Controls.Add(pic)

    AddHandler cboColor.DrawItem, Sub() 'Wathever you need here
    AddHandler cboColor.SelectedIndexChanged, Sub() pic.BackColor = Color.FromName([Enum].Parse(GetType(KnownColor), cboColor.Text).ToString)
End Sub
```

Or like jmcilhinney pointed out you can "link" controls with .Tag:

```
    cboColor.Tag = pic
    pic.Tag = cboColor

    AddHandler cboColor.SelectedIndexChanged, Sub(sender2, eventargs2)
                                          DirectCast(sender2.Tag, PictureBox).BackColor = Color.FromName([Enum].Parse(GetType(KnownColor), sender2.Text).ToString)
                                      End Sub
```

Or you can search Parent.Controls collection:

```
    AddHandler cboColor.SelectedIndexChanged, Sub(sender2, eventargs2)
            Dim TargetPic As PictureBox = (From f in Parent.Controls Where f.Name = sender2.Name.Replace("cboDetailColor", "picDetailColor") take 1).First()
            TargetPic.BackColor = Color.FromName([Enum].Parse(GetType(KnownColor), sender2.Text).ToString)
    End Sub
```

The last one may have performance issues based on control collection size.

Hope it helps.